# Cant use any string functions on xmlhttp response text in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I can't do anything with the response text from the below code other than print it to the screen. I want to use an if statement to check what the response text is,but whenever I try this it prints nothing.

For the sake of this example, assume the response text is "2"

Code:

```
Set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "POST", url,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
message = "test example"
xmlhttp.send(message)

if xmlhttp.responseText = "2"
response.Write("Found a 2")
end if
```

What's happening is if I just have response.Write(xmlhttp.responseText) it will print out the two, but when I try and do any string functions on the response text it ignores it and prints nothing

Any help appreciated

Comment: What string functions have you tried to use with the response text? Could you add an example to your post?

Comment: What I am trying to do is see if the string is equal to another, so using

if xmlhttp.responseText = "2"

and have also tried
if StrComp(responseText, "2", 1) = 0

which should do a textual compare and return 0 if they are the same. I am starting to wonder however if it is an issue with what is being returned, as StrReverse(responseText) is printing out a the xml response in reverse, even though the responseText normally appears to be just "2"

I will keep trying to work out what's going on and if you have any ideas please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the issue now. When you do response.Write(responseText), it will try and be clever without telling you and assume what you want to print is what's in the <return> </return> tags. However if you reverse the contents of the string, it gives you the whole xml response text. So I had to use InStr and Mid to find <return></return> within the xml and get the value between.

Answer (score 2):

responseText send you a string value "<"return>2<"/return> but when you print this value it is very intelegent so that only 2 will be printed. so when you compare with "2" it does not match.
I solved this problem by search() method.
for example....

var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

var found = response.search("2");

if(found != -1)
{
alert ( "Found a 2" );
}

explanation: this string1.search(string2) method send -1 if  string2 is not found in string1. but if found it send you the position of first found. so if the result is not -1 then it is sure that it string2 is found in string1. you can try in this way. i think you can solve your problem. best of luck.